# Two questions about this sentence that I just wrote

Tags: выражения

I just wrote this sentence for a Russian essay (for reference it's from Tolstoy's story *Filippok*, the tl;dr being that a boy who is considered too young to go to school by his teachers and parents learns the alphabet from his brother):

*Его желание учиться и настойчивость вопреки мнениям своей семьи и своего сообщества вели к тому, что он постучает в школу в раннем возрасте, научившись читать и писать с помощью своего брата.*

Two questions:

1. Is it grammatically correct? Does it make sense? This is the first time I've written a sense of this length or complexity (about 6 months ago I was writing *Это я. И это Тим. Привет, Тим!* etc and I just wanted to make sure I was on the right path).
2. Is the use of вопреки + dative to mean 'despite' the correct sense, even though the dictionary provided also несмотря на, and наперекор, I chose this one, mostly because the examples the dictionary gave for вопреки seemed closest to what I needed.

Big thanks for any help provided:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Его желание учиться и настойчивость вопреки мнениям своей семьи и своего сообщества(сообщество is too formal in this context, you might meant друзья и знакомые or окружение) вели(incorrect time form, you should use привели) к тому, что он постучает(probably this is a typo, the correct one is поступает) в школу в раннем возрасте, научившись читать и писать с помощью(this is correct but благодаря is more suitable here) своего брата.*

So the correct varaint is

*Его желание учиться и настойчивость вопреки мнению своей семьи и своего окружения привели к тому, что он поступает в школу в раннем возрасте, научившись читать и писать благодаря своему брату.*

1. Yes, that make a sense but `постучает` и `вели` are incorrect
2. Yes, it is

Comment: Thanks so much - exactly the answer I was looking for

Comment: @Elena спасибо, что заметили ошибки в склонении, изменю свой ответ

Comment: 1. I don't think you can use *своей/своего* here like this, _его_ is not an agent in this sentence. 2. There is a tense mismatch between *привели* and *поступает*: it's either *привели к тому, что он поступил* or *приводят к тому, что он поступает*.

Comment: "вели(incorrect time form, you should use привели) " - it's not necessarily. Depends on whether you want to emphasize the result or the process.

Answer (score 5):

I'll add something to the answer by @mihett05:

> Его желание учиться и настойчивость вопреки мнениям своей семьи и своего сообщества

*Свой* can only refer to the agent in a sentence. In your sentence, the agent is *желание и настойчивость*, they don't have the family. You can just omit it.

The clause with *вопреки* should immediately precede or follow the verb clause: *желание, вопреки мнению, учиться* or *желание учиться вопреки мнению*.

> *привели к тому, что он поступает в школу в раннем возрасте*

There is an aspect mismatch. *Поступает* is an imperfective verb describing a completed, non-recurring action. Since the verbs describing the cause and the effect both describe a completed action, it is stylistically better to put them in the same aspect: *привели к тому, что он поступил* or *приводят к тому, что он поступает*.

> Его настойчивость и желание учиться вопреки мнению семьи и общества привели к тому, что он поступил в школу в раннем возрасте, научившись читать и писать благодаря своему брату.